# Clang error with Theano after upgrading to macOS Sierra and Xcode 8.0

Tags: ios, clang, theano, macos-sierra

I recently upgraded from macOS Yosemite to Sierra and Xcode 8.0 (I am not sure what was the previous version of Xcode). Before updating everything worked fine.

My issue seems to be similar to these two:

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/4277

[MAC OSX10.11.4 python3 import theano error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36213642/mac-osx10-11-4-python3-import-theano-error)

Although these issues are with Theano 0.8 and Xcode 7.3 and I am using Theano 0.7 and Xcode 8.0. I can't upgrade to Theano 0.8 because my code is not compatible.

The error I get:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-sse4a'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-tbm'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-fma4'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-rtm'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-pku'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-hle'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-sha'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: unknown argument: '-target-feature'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+cx16'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+xsave'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+prfchw'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+bmi2'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+adx'
clang: error: language not recognized: 'savec'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+fsgsbase'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+avx'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+popcnt'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+fma'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+bmi'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+aes'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+rdrnd'
clang: error: language not recognized: 'saves'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+sse4.1'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+sse4.2'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+avx2'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+sse'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+lzcnt'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+pclmul'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+f16c'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+ssse3'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+mmx'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+cmov'
clang: error: language not recognized: 'op'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+rdseed'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+movbe'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+xsaveopt'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+sse2'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '+sse3'
```

Also this gets printed to stderr: https://gist.github.com/mozkal/839c12d5afcbd8073a9b744ec6020f27

Do you have any ideas why this happens? Could the cause of this be different than a bug in Xcode/CLT? If this is a bug, can you think of any workarounds? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You'll need to install older Xcode + command-line tools or [install gcc](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/3415#issuecomment-221845539) and hopefully make it work that way...

Comment: I downloaded Xcode 7.2.1 and it helped. Thanks